# Shopify API date format not matching Ruby date format

Tags: ruby, shopify

I'm trying to implement a calendar that displays Shopify blog posts as they are published. I've set up a calendars controller as followers:

```
def index
@articles = ShopifyAPI::Article.find(:all)
@articles_by_date = @articles.group_by(&:published_at)
@articles_by_date = @articles.group_by { |x| Date.parse(x.published_at).strftime("%-d %Y-%m-%d") } end
```

I've also set up a calendar view using the railscasts tutorial(http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised). Here is the code for the calendar view(exactly as in Railscasts):

```
<%= calendar do |date| %>
<%= date.day %>
<% if @articles_by_date[date] %>
<ul>
  <% @articles_by_date[date].each do |article| %>
    <li><%= article.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

When I open up the Calendar view, the blog post doesn't show up. I've added some test posts to my store in this month.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What did you mean by `%-d` in your strftime format?

Comment: [I can’t see the `-d` timezone here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime). BTW, `Date.parse(Time.now.to_s).strftime("%-d %Y-%m-%d")` prints out `"15 2015-01-15"` which I doubt is what you expected.

Comment: The format Shopify uses is this: 2015-01-04T13:05:00-05:00

Comment: As mudasobwa pointed out, the format string looks wrong and will print out dates in this format: "15 2015-01-15" and will group articles into groups with keys like this: `'15 2015-01-15', '16 2015-01-16'` and so on.  

Are you sure that matches the format of the block parameter `date` in  `calendar do |date|`? I'm guessing it does not and thus `@articles_by_date[date]` will always be `nil`

Comment: I found a site called strftimer.com where you can enter the date format and it will give you the strftime expression - the one it gives for this format is time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%H:%M") - I tried using this, but still no luck.